# Trying to manipulate string such as if '26169;#c785643', then the result should be like 'c785643'

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to manipulate string data in a column such as if the given string is `'20591;#e123456;#17507;#c567890;#15518;#e135791'` or `'26169;#c785643'`, then the 
result should be like `'e123456;c567890;e135791'` or `'c785643'`. The number of digits in between can be of any length.

Some of the things I have tried so far are:

1. `select replace('20591;#e123456;#17507;#c567890;#15518;#e135791','#','');`

This leaves me with `'20591;e123456;17507;c567890;15518;e135791'`, which still includes the digits without 'e' or 'c' prefixed to them. i want to get rid of 20591, 17507 and 15518.

2. Create function that will keep a pattern of `'%[#][ec][0-9][;]%'` and will get rid of the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important advise is: Do not store any data in a delimited string. This is violating the most basic principle of relational database concepts (1.NF).

The second hint is SO-related: Please always add / tag your questions with the appropriate tool. The tag `[tsql]` points to SQL-Server, but this might be wrong (which would invalidate both answers). Please tag the full product with its version (e.g. [sql-server-2012]). Especially with string splitting there are very important product related changes from version to version.

Now to your question.

### Working with (almost) any version of SQL-Server

My suggestion uses a trick with XML:

(credits to Alan Burstein for the *mockup*)

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (someid INT IDENTITY, somestring VARCHAR(50)); 
INSERT @table VALUES ('20591;#e123456;#17507;#c567890;#15518;#e135791'),('26169;#c785643')
```

--the query

```
SELECT t.someid,t.somestring,A.CastedToXml
      ,STUFF(REPLACE(A.CastedToXml.query('/x[contains(text()[1],"#") and empty(substring(text()[1],2,100) cast as xs:int?)]')
                                  .value('.','nvarchar(max)'),'#',';'),1,1,'') TheNewList 
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.somestring,';','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(CastedToXml);
```

The idea in short:

By replacing the `;` with XML tags `</x><x>` we can transform your delimited list to XML. I included the intermediate XML into the result set. Just click it to see how this works.

In the next query I use a XQuery predicate first to find entries, which contain a `#` and second, which do NOT cast to an integer without the `#`.

The thrid step is specific to XML again. The XPath `.` in `.value()` will return all content as one string.

Finally we have to replace the `#` with `;` and cut away the leading `;` using `STUFF()`.

### UPDATE The same idea, but a bit shorter:

You can try this as well

```
SELECT t.someid,t.somestring,A.CastedToXml
  ,REPLACE(A.CastedToXml.query('data(/x[empty(. cast as xs:int?)])')
                        .value('.','nvarchar(max)'),' ',';') TheNewList 
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.somestring,';#','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(CastedToXml);
```

Here I use `;#` to split your string and `data()` to implicitly concatenate your values (blank-separated).

### UPDATE 2 for v2017

If you have v2017+ I'd suggest a combination of a JSON splitter and `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT t.someid,STRING_AGG(A.[value],';') AS TheNewList
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(t.somestring,';#','","'),'"]')) A
WHERE TRY_CAST(A.[value] AS INT) IS NULL
GROUP BY t.someid;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Shnugo! I apologize as I this is my first post, and I will keep those points in mind for the future. 
I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @YadneshBandekar no problem, welcome and happy coding 

Comment: I am trying to keep everything consistent. I have been using char manipulation functions throughout for other columns, and would like to keep things consistent for the people working in the future :) Is there a solution that doesn't involve XQuery? [Though, I must say it works beautifully though]. Thanks again!! :)

Comment: @HumbleBeginnings I can understand what you want, but: SQL-Server is not very good in string manipulations... Splitting an undefined length string with simple string functions will need either a loop or a recursice CTE. And re-concatenating the fragments after cleaning will again need rather ugly work arounds. You can follow Alan Burstein's answer and replace `STRING_SPLIT()` (came with v2016) with one of the many string splitting functions you will find out there...

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the version of SQL Server you are on. If you are using 2016+ you can use `SPLIT_STRING`, otherwise a [good T-SQL splitter](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) will do.

**Against a single variable:**

```
DECLARE @somestring VARCHAR(1000) = '20591;#e123456;#17507;#c567890;#15518;#e135791';

SELECT NewString = STUFF((
  SELECT      ','+split.item
  FROM        STRING_SPLIT(@somestring,';') AS s
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(s.[value],'#',''))) AS split(item)
  WHERE       split.item LIKE '[a-z][0-9]%'
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');
```

**Against a table:**

```
NewString
----------------------
e123456,c567890,e135791

-- Against a table
DECLARE @table TABLE (someid INT IDENTITY, somestring VARCHAR(50));
INSERT @table VALUES ('20591;#e123456;#17507;#c567890;#15518;#e135791'),('26169;#c785643')

SELECT t.*, fn.NewString
FROM   @table AS t
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT NewString = STUFF((
    SELECT      ','+split.item
    FROM        STRING_SPLIT(t.somestring,';') AS s
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(s.[value],'#',''))) AS split(item)
    WHERE       split.item LIKE '[a-z][0-9]%'
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
) AS fn;
```

**Returns:**

```
someid      somestring                                         NewString
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------------------------
1           20591;#e123456;#17507;#c567890;#15518;#e135791     e123456,c567890,e135791
2           26169;#c785643                                     c785643
```

Comment: Hi Alan, until MS does not add a *position* to `STRING_SPLIT()`'s result I'd avoid this function... With v2016 we have the (almost) equally fast JSON-array, which guarantees the given order...

Comment: thank you @Alan. Is there a workaround that doesn't use XML.

Comment: @HumbleBeginnings Not before v2017 (which brought `STRING_AGG()`). Any other approach will need even more clumsy code...